# Can fetch get object as headers?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to understand how to use whatwg `fetch` according to specifications. Specifically, if I can do this, according to the specs.

```
fetch("https://example.org", {headers:{'Content-Type', 'image/jpeg'}})
```

This is actually possible with [github's fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch), that is, according to their words, "as closely as possible to the standard Fetch specification".

When I read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch), I read this

> `headers`: Any headers you want to add to your request, contained within a `Headers` object or `ByteString`.

*(edit: I have now edited the MDN pages so they no longer talk about `Headers` initialization by `ByteString` directly.)*

That means ordinary object is not allowed.

But, this documentation isn't perfect, so I went to the spec, that are written in their usual verbose way, and I find this:

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request-class

> Request class
>
> ```
> Constructor(RequestInfo input, optional RequestInit init)
>
> dictionary RequestInit {
> ...
>   HeadersInit headers;
> ...
> }
>
> typedef (Headers or sequence<sequence<ByteString>> or OpenEndedDictionary<ByteString>) HeadersInit;
> ```
>
> OpenEndedDictionary is a future IDL construct. Expect it to be used
>   as such:
>
> ```
> var meta = { "Content-Type": "text/xml", "Breaking-Bad": "<3" }
> new Headers(meta)
> ```

If I read this correctly, this means that the object actually can be used (and `OpenEndedDictionary` is... just an object). Do I understand it correctly?

(I will add that, with my experimentation, both Firefox and Chrome accepts the header object.)

I also cannot see anything about the `headers` being possible to instantiate from `ByteString` directly as the MDN suggests.

What I am also interested is what the different implementations *actually* accept right now.

Comment: "`OpenEndedDictionary` definition" googling just returns me some random github's issues and websters dictionary definition of the word "open-ended".

Comment: The problem here is that `OpenEndedDictionary` *is not defined anywhere yet*.  (That's what they mean by "`OpenEndedDictionary<T>` is a future IDL construct.") It's used in the typedef for `HeadersInit`, but the spec doesn't formally say what an `OpenEndedDictionary` is or how it behaves. The spec gives a little note about how it will *probably* work whenever the authors get around to defining it. Thus, it's not clear whether a particular implementation can be spec compliant on this point, since the spec is explicitly vague on this point (and will someday be less vague).

Comment: OK, in that case, I added a note to my question: "What I am also interested is what the different implementations actually accept right now."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this code:

```js
var r = new Request('test.html', {
  headers: {
    'Custom-Header': 'test',
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
  }
});
for (h of r.headers) alert(JSON.stringify(h));
```

It works for Firefox and Chrome. I did not try in Opera which are [the browsers currently supporting Fetch API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch).

By the way, MDN does not suggest to instantiate from `ByteString`. Actually, it's saying that [`ByteString` is just `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ByteString) in JavaScript.

Comment: "Any headers you want to add to your request, contained within a ... ByteString." - that to me sounds  like you can make Headers object from string, as `new Headers("Header: Test")`, but it should not be possible according to the specs.

Comment: You're right. The explanation is inaccurate and misleading. Maybe you could reword it as it's a collaborative wiki.

Comment: I did not want to reword it since I don't understand it :) but OK I will

Comment: I have edited your answer so it actually works + that it is a runnable snippet

Comment: I did not know that feature. Thank you very much. It is quite cool.

Comment: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: OK I edited the MDN pages to the best of my knowledge :)